# To Perform Maven Release; Build Environment field is not appering in the Hudson Project's configuration

Tags: hudson, jenkins, maven-release-plugin, jenkins-plugins

I am very new to Hudson/Jenkins and I am following the Continuous Integration with jenkins.pdf. And I want to perform maven release. To do this the book says, the Hudson M2 Extra steps plug in and M2release plug in should be installed. I did all those part But at least to configure Maven release build, "Build environment" part which should be appeared in the Project's configuration is not there. Where I have made the mistakes. Help me.

Answer (score 6):

Your question lacks any information whatsoever.

What jenkins.pdf? What book? Provide a link maybe, so that we would at least know what you are referring to.

**Build Environment** section is *after* **Build** and **Build Settings** sections
It is also *before* the **Post-build Actions** section

When you check mark **Configure M2 Extra Build Steps**, more options will be shown.
If you don't see **Configure M2 Extra Build Steps**, you are probably not configuring a "*Maven*" project (maybe you are doing "*free-style*").

Jenkins/Hudson doesn't let you change the type of project job after it is first created, nor does it show anywhere what type it is.
Go back to Hudson/Jenkins dashboard, and click **New Job**. Make sure to select **Build a maven2/3 project**. Then look for those steps in this project

Comment: So free-style project does not support "Build Environment" plugin? I created a free-style project. Later added the above plugin. It doesn't show in configuration even after restart. But it does show in the "installed"  list of plugins

Comment: Try "re-creating" a project after the plugin had been added.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with add [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), after i installed it:

- Manage Jenkins->Manage Plugins->Available

my problem is solved and Build Environments start to seen in my configuration.